# adding values to an array through an if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, if-statement

I get values and ids from a form input using onkeyup(). If the value is between 0 and 4 I want to add it to an array. However it seems my function adds values to the array regardless if they are between 0 and 4 eventhough I want it to add values to the array only when the value is between 0 and 4. What am I doing wrong?

**These are the inputs:**

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id=0 onkeyup="a(this)" mix="0" max="4">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id=1 onkeyup="a(this)" mix="0" max="4">
.
.
```

**This is my function:**

```
function a(c){

    var dps = [];
    var id = c.id;
    var valueStr = c.value;
    var value = parseInt(valueStr)
    if (0 <= value <= 4) {
        dps[id]=value;
        console.log("id: ",id);
        console.log("value: ", value);
        console.log("length of array: ",dps.length);
        console.log("type of value: ", typeof value);
    }
 }
```

I have recreated it on Jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/89az7u4n/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you typically write inequalities in mathematics is different from the way we typically write comparisons in most programming languages.

`if (0 <= value <= 4)` doesn't mean 'if the value is between 0 and 4'. The parser treats this as `(0 <= value) <= 4` which will either evaluate to `false <= 4` or `true <= 4` which both evaluate to `true`.

Change your `if` statement to this:

```
if (0 <= value && value <= 4) {
  ...
}
```

Where `&&` is the [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) operator.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should split your condition into two statements like this:

```
if (0 <= value && value <= 4) {
```

instead?

Answer (score 1):

### N.B.

1. You should avoid using inline on* handlers (onclick, onchange, onkeyup, etc) and use event listeners instead.
2. Change `mix="0"` to `min="0"`.
3. You need to use the `&&` (**AND operator**) in your `if condition` as shown and explained in *@p.s.w.g*'s answer.

---

### SOLUTION:

If both your inputs are kept next to each other, just wrap them inside a common div and target them both using the [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method and then use the [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to add a `keyup` listener to both the inputs that will run a function checking the input values when the event is invoked.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```js
/* JavaScript */

const inputVal = document.querySelectorAll("#someDiv input");
let dps = [];

inputVal.forEach(input => input.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  let value = parseInt(input.value);
 if (value >= 0 && value <= 4){
   dps[input.id] = value;
    console.log(dps);
  }  
}));
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div id="someDiv">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="0" min="0" max="4">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="1" min="0" max="4">
</div>
```

---

If your input elements are not kept next to each other, just target them separately using the [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method and then add a `keyup` listener to both the inputs that will run a function checking the input values when the event is invoked.

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```js
/* JavaScript */

const inputVal1 = document.getElementById("0");
const inputVal2 = document.getElementById("1");
let dps = [];

function checkVal(){
  let value = parseInt(this.value);
 if (value >= 0 && value <= 4){
   dps[this.id] = value;
    console.log(dps);
  }  
}

inputVal1.addEventListener("keyup", checkVal);
inputVal2.addEventListener("keyup", checkVal);
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="0" min="0" max="4">
<div>ABCD</div>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="1" min="0" max="4">
```